# How to handle 3 digits hours while convert/format a textfile import in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I would like to get a hint, how to handle 3 digit hours while convert/format a textfile-import, because Access is not able to work with those kind of data.

This is a sample:

08:45:00 = 8,75 that works fine, but if there is a much hihgher amount of hours for example 116:15:00 the Datetime Format does not work.

Is there a chance to get something like this:
08:45:00 -(8,75/8,75)-> 1,0
116:15:00 -(116,25/8,75)-> 13,29

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What are these times? Bad inputs by someone or legitimate data? What are you trying to do with the second part there? Turn it to decimal?

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this:

```
 $x = '116:30:00'
 (iex ('New-Timespan -Hours {0} -Minutes {1} -Seconds {2}' -f $x.split(':'))).totalhours
```

116.5